# Why isn't the scroll bar connecting

Tags: scrollbar

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as smxg

root = Tk()
root.geometry("675x456")
root.title("To Do List")

# Create a Frame to contain your widgets

# Function to link the scrollbar to the frame's yview

var_ = {}
scroll = Scrollbar(root,)

#canva.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.pack(fill=Y,side=RIGHT)
canva = Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

canva.pack(fill="both")
scroll.config(command=canva.yview)
def done():
    for u in range(1, 6):
        if var_[u].get() == 1:
            with open("task_data.txt", mode="a") as f:
                f.write(f"Today you have done {l[u]}\n")
        if scale_var.get() >= 6:
            smxg.askquestion("Fine day", "What happened? Why are you sad?")
    smxg.askyesnocancel("Confirmation", "Are you sure you want to submit?")

l = ["", "coding", "exercise", "study", "game", "walking"]

Label( text="To-Do List", font="bold,15,bold").pack()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side = "right",anchor="center")

# Frame for scale and "How's your day" label
scale_frame = Frame(frame)
scale_frame.pack(padx=20)

scale_var = Scale(scale_frame, from_=1, to=10)
scale_var.pack()
Label(scale_frame, text="How's your day", justify="right").pack()

for i in range(1, 6):
    var_[i] = IntVar()
    Label( text=f"\n\n{i}. {l[i].title()}", font="Times,10,bold").pack(anchor="nw")
    Checkbutton( variable=var_[i]).pack()

Button(frame, text="Submit", command=done).pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting a scroll bar in right side using canvas and pack

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!